# Stripe Email Receipt Items

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Charge API for billing of 1 or more items. Future billing is allowed by using Stripe's Customer API. Now, I'm trying to use Stripe's Email Receipts, but I want to display multiple items in the summary. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to line items on an Invoice created by a Subscription, they will appear on the email receipt automatically.

Comment: Not necessarily the invoice by subscription, but the Charge API itself creates an email receipt describing the payment. The default item in the summary is "Payment to {APP_NAME} - {AMOUNT}" and you can override this by passing a "description" parameter. I just can't figure out if it's possible to itemize the receipt.

Comment: Well I see it is possible when using Invoice and InvoiceItem API. I was just curious if it could be done by the Charge API alone which has been our previous implementation.